# reading and saving large files rds files in a single rds file

Tags: r

I have a list that contain many large files. All the files have the same column names. I want to combine them into an rds file and save.

```
  list.nam<- list.files(pattern="*.I S")
    list.fil <- lapply (list.nam, readRDs) 

Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'readRDs' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have entered a incorrect function name, replace readRDs with readRDS it works

```
list.fil <- lapply (list.nam, readRDS)
```

Comment: @runjumpfly Please justify your function by syntax help(readRDS), vote up if you feel its works